# MSSQL - How to tranform cpu_time(ms) usage into percentage?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I transforme TOTAL CPU (ms or milliseconds) to percentagem?

For example with the cpu_time column in sys.dm_exec_requests.

```
select cpu_time from dm_exec_requests
```

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by transform it to percentage? Are you referring to CPU load?

The cpu_time is the elapsed cpu time for the request.
The closes you will come is probably taking the cpu_time and dividing it with the result of the total_elapsed_time (exists in the same DMV) multiplied with the number of logical cpu cores you have available to SQL server. I believe this will be some average load over the execution time of the request, but to me it doesn't seem very useful.